# libcurl for android ndk-build with out android source

Tags: android-ndk, libcurl

I tried to build the libcurl with andriod ndk with the information provided in this link  https://github.com/jahrome/curl-android.git but I could not do it  because it needs android source code also ... Is there any other way to make the CURL build for android ndk-build..

Comment: May I suggest using Android's built-in HTTP stack instead? The one with the all-Java interface?

Comment: in future I need to  support the openssl also , so I thought of compiling the own curl and openssl part .

Answer (score 1):

See http://boinc.berkeley.edu/android-boinc/readme.txt

Comment: what this has to do with cURL?

Comment: @JaakL: http://boinc.berkeley.edu/android-boinc/curl-7.22.0/ isn't good enough for you?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest building libcurl inside docker container - http://vitiy.info/dockerfile-example-to-compile-libcurl-for-android-inside-docker-container/

In short - download NDK, make stand-alone toolchain with *make-standalone-toolchain.sh* script, set env variables to toolchain compiler and build all libs with cross-compilation configure flags (if necessary).